# Avoid padding with NA when using dplyr::left_join

Tags: r

I am joining two dataframes using `left_join` from `dplyr`. Here is a MWE:

```
library(dplyr)

dfOne <- data.frame(1:10, 
                    8*(1:10),
                    c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20) )
colnames(dfOne)<-c("one", "two", "three")


dfTwo <- data.frame(1:6, 
                    8*(1:6),
                    c(2,4,6,8,10,12) )
colnames(dfTwo)<-c("one", "two", "three")


left_join(dfOne[c("one", "two")], dfTwo[c("two", "three")], by="two")
```

This gives the following output (as expected)

```
   one two three
1    1   8     2
2    2  16     4
3    3  24     6
4    4  32     8
5    5  40    10
6    6  48    12
7    7  56    NA
8    8  64    NA
9    9  72    NA
10  10  80    NA
```

Column `three` is padded with `NA` at all rows where `dfTwo$two` doesn't exist in `dfTwo$one`. However, is it possible to use `left_join` in a way such that we avoid the `NA`-values and they are empty (`NULL`) instead?

Comment: Do you want `inner_join` instead of `left_join`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I am it might be helpful to understand that NA in R is the same as Null in SQL. If you want NA to appear as "" simply name your dataframe in the left join (for example "lj_df") and replace all the NA's. You could replace with "" with 0 or "Null" or anything else you like.

```
lj_df <- left_join(dfOne[c("one", "two")], dfTwo[c("two", "three")], by="two")    
lj_df[is.na(lj_df)] <- ""
```